# Drawing a grid in PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am trying to draw a grid in a QGraphicsScene. More specifically, I want a 256 x 256 grid of 32x32 pixel cells, where the cells are separated by 1-pixel thick borders on all sides (including at the boundaries of the entire grid). So the width and height of the entire scene should be (256*32 + 257) = 8449 pixels. I have tried doing this by drawing the lines using QGraphicsLineItem. I then opened a screenshot and measured my cells and noticed that their widths/heights were between 40 and 41 pixels (some were not even square). I assume the problem must be related to the different coordinate systems (item, scene, and view coordinates) involved here. I didn't really understand the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/graphicsview.html#:%7E:text=View%20Coordinates,-View%20coordinates%20are&text=The%20top%20left%20corner%20of,viewport%20width%2C%20viewport%20height) regarding this.

Most notably, the documentation says that, in view coordinates, the top-left corner is (0, 0), while the bottom-right corner is (view.width, view.height). How can this possibly be? These coordinates are 0-indexed, so this would result in dimensions of (view.width + 1) x (view.height + 1).

Here is my attempt

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsLineItem, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QFrame
from PyQt6.QtGui import QColor, QPen

app = QApplication([])

scene = QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 8448,8448)
scene.setBackgroundBrush(QColor(0, 255, 0))

for i in range(0, 8449, 33):
    pen = QPen(QColor(0, 0, 255))
    pen.setWidth(0)
    horizontal_line = QGraphicsLineItem(0, 0, 8448, 0)
    horizontal_line.setPen(pen)
    horizontal_line.setPos(0, i)
    scene.addItem(horizontal_line)
    horizontal_line.setOpacity(0.5)
    vertical_line = QGraphicsLineItem(0, 0, 0, 8448)
    vertical_line.setPen(pen)
    vertical_line.setPos(i, 0)
    vertical_line.setOpacity(0.5)
    scene.addItem(vertical_line)

window = QMainWindow()
window.show()

container = QFrame(parent=window)
vlayout = QVBoxLayout()

view = QGraphicsView(scene, parent=container)
vlayout.addWidget(view)

container.setLayout(vlayout)
window.setCentralWidget(container)

view.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on arch-linux using qt-6.6.0. I used a screen-ruler utility (kruler) to measure the squares, and the spacing is entirely uniform - i.e. every one is 34x34 (including the lines). If you're measuring 40/41, it seems there must be some scaling going on somewhere when you create the screenshot.

Comment: @ekhumoro It seems to have to do with the container widget the view is placed in, and the layout of the container in the example. I tried putting QGraphicsView object inside a QMainWaindow object and now the cells are almost correct, though some are 1 pixel small in at least one dimension. In my actual program, the QGraphicsView object is in a widget with a QVBoxLayout layout, which also produces oversized cells.

Comment: You really must provide a proper [mre] if you want help with this.

Comment: @ekhumoro I updated my example to include a container widget for the QGraphicsView and tested that indeed the cells are coming out to 40x40ish.

Comment: Do a preliminary research. See [High DPI Displays](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/highdpi.html).

Comment: @relent95 Thanks, that helps. I don't understand how I can change the device pixel ratio, though. Everything in the documentation seems to be talking about changing environment variables for testing purposes. Can it actually be changed within the program?

Comment: You can set environment variables with the ```os.environ``` before importing PyQt libraries. But it's not recommended, because fixing the DPI scaling is ignoring the OS suggestions and a user preference.

Comment: Fantastic. That worked. Thank you.

Comment: Why not answer your own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the flag

```
os.environ["QT_ENABLE_HIGHDPI_SCALING"] = "0"
```

disables the high-DPI scaling, allowing you to place items on the scene in terms of physical pixels.